# How to capture table in a structured format from the website using Beautiful soup and Pandas or any other method?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the table '***Summary statement holding of specified securities***' from this website https://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/infosys-ltd/infy/500209/shareholding-pattern/ I tried scraping data using selenium but it was all in one column without any table and there is no unique identifier to this table. How to use pandas and Beautiful Soup to scrape the table in a structured format or any other method. This is the code I'm trying to figure out but it didn't work.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0"
}

params = {
    'id': 0,
    'txtscripcd': '',
    'pagecont': '',
    'subject': ''
}

def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
    df = pd.read_html(r.content)[-1].iloc[:, :-1]
    print(df)

main("")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load the table to DataFrame and csv, you can use this example:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0'}
api_url = 'https://api.bseindia.com/BseIndiaAPI/api/shpSecSummery_New/w?qtrid=&scripcode=500209'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(api_url, headers=headers).json()['Data'], 'lxml')
table = soup.select_one('b:contains("Summary statement holding of specified securities")').find_next('table')
df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0].iloc[2:, :]

df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: You forgot to import `pandas`

Comment: @AndrejKesely Thanks for the solution worked charm but I want to automate the solution in selenium for certain websites with an exactly similar structure. How should I fetch the api_url for those or is there any other way?

Comment: @codeit94 For this site, try to update `scripcode=` (this is the number `500209` in the main URL). For other sites - you have to observe where is the page making requests and capture the URL/cookies/headers... I'm afraid, there isn't possibility for much automation.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Thanks ,Got the jist :)

Comment: @AndrejKesely How to remove the column index while moving dataframe to excel?

Comment: @codeit94 You can try `df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False, header=False)`

Comment: @AndrejKesely I actually automated the solution but need one help. I want to all these multiple tables in a single sheet with the Company name in front of it in first column.How to go about it?

Comment: @codeit94 To not clutter the comment section, I suggest to open a new question here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

The data you are looking for is in served by the following API endpoint:

```
https://api.bseindia.com/BseIndiaAPI/api/shpSecSummery_New/w?qtrid=&scripcode=500209
```

Where **scripcode** is the unique identifier.

The API is not checking for cookies/session so direct call to this endpoint would return you the data you are looking for.